# Python splitting ast.assign

Tags: python-2.7, abstract-syntax-tree

So in Python there is the normal single assignment:

```
x = 0
y = 0
```

As well as the multiple-assignment (basically implicit tuple unpacking)

```
x,y = 0,0
```

In both cases, python generates `ast.Assign` nodes. The first would generate two nodes with `ast.Name` nodes as targets and `ast.Num`nodes as their values.

```
Assign
    targets = [ast.Name(id = 'x')]
    value = ast.Num(n=0)

Assign
    targets = [ast.Name(id = 'y')]
    value = ast.Num(n=0)
```

The second one, however generates something like this.

```
Assign
    targets = [ast.Tuple(elts = [ast.Name(id='x'), ast.Name(id='y')])]
    value = ast.Tuple(elts = [ast.Num(n=0), ast.Num(n=0)])
```

How do I convert the second compound assignment into two Assign nodes in the context of `ast.NodeTransformer`? I've tried directly converting it by zipping elements together into `ast.Assign`nodes, but the problem is that `NodeTransformer` expects one node back (AFAIK) instead of a list of nodes.

Comment: as far as I can tell you'd have to use a `ast.Module` node containing each assignment, but if the target was an iterable like `a,b = tup` you wouldn't be able to seperate that.